# Prestashop importing csv js widget error

Tags: javascript, csv, import, prestashop

I'm trying to import csv file in prestahop admin station but a JS Error appear in chrome dev console.

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   jquery.ui.widget.min.js:4e.Widget._createWidget
>   jquery.ui.widget.min.js:4e.(anonymous function). (anonymous function)
>   jquery.ui.widget.min.js:4(anonymous function)
>   jquery.ui.widget.min.js:4n.extend.each
>   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2n.fn.n.each jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2e.fn.
>   (anonymous function) jquery.ui.widget.min.js:4(anonymous function)
>   index.php?controller=AdminImport&token=822bd83cedc387e5887cd66d73ce92cd:1201j
>   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2k.fireWith jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2n.extend.ready
>   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2K jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2

and this make the import page unusable

what to do ?

Comment: I have no special code just the admin dashboard is not working as it must work

Comment: You may need to use more updated version of PrestaShop and if you are using the latest version, then this is a bug that you should report to PrestaShop.

Comment: Yes this is the lastes version I just downloaded I will try a new install. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Just Reinstalled prestashop and everything runs perfectly it must be a bad ftp copy